# How to match to the longest pattern

Tags: python, python-re

How do I modify the following to match `abbb` instead of just stop at ab?

```py
>>> re.match('ab|abb|abbb', 'abbb')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 2), match='ab'>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
re.match('ab(b(b)?)?', 'abbb')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='abbb'>
```

The `?` here means that the preceding item is optional, but it is greedy, so the item will be included in the match if possible (the lazy equivalent is `??`).

The inner parentheses are not required here (because they enclose only a single character) but are included to make it more obvious you might extend it to a longer sequence.  All that you strictly need is:

```
re.match('ab(bb?)?', 'abbb')
```

The above does not depend on the fact that the `b` is repeated in the pattern, for example you could similarly have:

```
re.match('ab(c(d)?)?', 'abcd')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='abcd'>
```

However, if in fact you do not require the generality of this approach, then you could instead use the following to match `a` followed by 1 to 3 `b`s:

```
re.match('ab{1,3}', 'abbb')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='abbb'>
```

Again, the `{1,3}` quantifier is greedy so will match as many as possible.  (The lazy equivalent is `{1,3}?`.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the order of your patterns. Try

```
re.match('abbb|abb|ab', 'abbb')
```